# compile lynx browser with ssl

Tags: 16.04, compiling, ssl, https, lynx

cannot get compiled lynx to work with https.

```
./configure --with-ssl --with-gnutls --with-gnutls-openssl
make
sudo make install
compile reports (in part):
checking if you want ssl library... yes
checking if you want gnutls support... yes
checking if you want gnutls-openssl compat... no
....
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin//pkg-config
checking pkg-config for openssl... yes
```

seems to go well. no error messages.
`lynx` installs at `/usr/local/bin/lynx`

```
/usr/local/bin/lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.9dev.9 (10 Apr 2016)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips, ncurses 6.0.20160213
Built on linux-gnu (Jul  7 2016 09:46:43).
```

yet, starting `/usr/local/bin/lynx`, then attempting to access https site fails with message: `this client does not contain support for HTTPS URLs`

i am running ubuntu 16.04.

further:

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

works smoothly, installs at `/usr/bin/lynx` and permits access to HTTPS.

lynx in ubuntu package:

```
$/usr/bin/lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.9dev.8 (21 Dec 2015)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, GNUTLS 3.4.9, ncurses 6.0.20160213(wide)
Built on linux-gnu.
```

why can't i get the compiled version to do right? surely, i am simply failing to set a flag ... but which?

any suggestions?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I note that, in spite of your `--with-gnutls --with-gnutls-openssl` options, your built version does NOT mention `GNUTLS`, while the working version does.

Re-read all the files in the Lynx package directory that have shouty names (`README*`,`INSTALL`,...) and anything whose filename contains `TLS`, `SSL`, etc.